# Lotus Notes Interop.Domino.dll for 64 bit OS

Tags: interop-domino

I have created a simple application of reading mail properties from a nsf file using Interop.Domino.dll, things works fine for 32 bit OS but when i attempt to run the same application under 64 bit OS i am unable to create LotusNotes Session , getting the COM Exception. Though i can run the same application on 64 bit by changing the plaform to "x86" but if i change the platform to "Any CPU" its not working.

I have few other dlls which are meanted for 64 bit machine so i need to keep the Platform to "Any CPU", but in this scenerio i am unable to register the Interop.Domino.dll

Is there any Solution to it.

Thanks and Regards,
Haseena

Comment: What do you mean by server or client APIs?
Are you refering to interop.domino.dll or interop.lotus.dll
I have the same issues compiling my application and making it run on 64 systems (works fine on 32)

Comment: I am using interop.domino.dll. Is there a 64 bit version for the same? can you please explain me the difference between interop.domino.dll and interop.lotus.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Domino *server* api is available in x86 *and* x64 flavors, so you would need to build against the appropriate one. The *client* api is x86 only, and if you are linking to that, it would behave the way you describe.